# reading raw data from a cdrom

Tags: laser

Can you point me some technical resources on how cdrom works and is it possible or lets say how easy to make a diy cdrom ? I am interested in reading and processing raw data from cd, not using a chip to decode EFM etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you will get direct links in other answers. I'd suggest googling for the particular components of a CD drive: CD focus, tracking, decoding, etc...

An even better method is probably to open a CD player (preferably an Audio CD because of low data rates) and to look at the signals using a scope. I have even done this with hard disks and it is pretty informative.

Comment: Thank you. Is it safe to work with it powered since it is a laser product ? I have a 25mhz oscilloscope, is it ok to work with it -I have no idea about the bandwidth of internals in cd- ?

Comment: The laser beam is focused on the CD and reflected light shouldn't be harmful during reading. So it should be safe with a CD in. To be sure, don't put your head into the imaginary beam. The nominal data rate 2,1 Mbit plus a litte bit for FEC, you should be able to see that on your oscilloscope. For a thorough understanding of the system you are interested in other signals than the data stream, anyway. Give it a try. :)